# Mysql INSERT if date column day is not current

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to perform an INSERT if there is no row for a user for the current day, or perform an update if the TIMESTAMP is the current day.
I think I could do this through an if else statement in PHP but I thought it would be cleaner if I did it through an mysql statement. I have my date column in the following format:
`Date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I think it would be cleaner for a condition in PHP, rather than executing something in MySQL unnecessarily...

Comment: Timestamp php != SQL timestamp..

Comment: I thought it might be cleaner because I would be performing a mysql statement anyway.If there is some way I could do a WHERE date not today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change data type to DATE,
Create Unique key (user, date)
and use

```
INSERT INTO table (user, date, field1, field2)
VALUES('user', CURDATE(), 'field1', 'field2')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field1=VALUES(field1), field2=VALUES(field2)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create another field with just the date (DATE type), make it a key, and then use:

```
INSERT INTO table (field1,field2...,field_date) VALUES (x,y,...,day)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field1=x, field2=y, ...
```